# Can't compile against Boost.log on OS X

Tags: c++, logging, boost, xcode4

I'm trying to build and run the tutorial examples for `Boost.log` and getting a compiler error that has me stumped and could use some help. Basic details; I've done a build of boost on OS X with `boost.log` included,yet when I try to compile any of the tutorial examples I get an overloaded `'operator>>'` error from inside boost log's `'trivial.hpp'` include file.

the errors are reported to be in

`log/utility/explicit_operator_bool.hpp`

here's the stack:

```
/usr/local/include/boost/log/utility/explicit_operator_bool.hpp:67:29: error: overloaded 'operator>>' must have at least one parameter of class or enumeration type [2]
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/log/attributes/attribute_name.hpp:27:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/log/attributes/attribute_set.hpp:28:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/log/sources/basic_logger.hpp:37:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/log/sources/severity_logger.hpp:27:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/log/trivial.hpp:25:
In file included from /Volumes/Macintosh HD 2/code/Logging Tut   1/loggingTut1/loggingTut1/main.cpp:18:
Overloaded 'operator>>' must have at least one parameter of class or enumeration type in /usr/local/include/boost/log/utility/explicit_operator_bool.hpp
```

Had a good look around to see if anyone else had something like this and I found nothing - so can anyone explain what i've missed or what the problem might be?

**The details:**

I'm trying this on OS X (10.6.8) using Xcode 4.0.2

I have downloaded and built the 1_46_1 boost version and that works fine with my primary boost-based project (using Boost Asio, boost threads etc).

`Boost.log` is not in the main build yet so I downloaded it from sourceforge as in this question:
[boost-log-how-to-get-it-and-how-to-build-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076405/what-is-boost-log-how-to-get-it-and-how-to-build-it)

I copied the `boost/log` directory from the downloaded branch into `boost_1_46_1/boost/log` directory, and copied the `libs/log` directory into the `boost_1_46_1/libs/log`

I removed all the boost stuff from `/usr/local/include/boost` and from `/usr/local/lib` and then re-built using:

`./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=all --prefix=/usr/local --includedir=/usr/local/include --libdir=/usr/local/lib`

followed by

`sudo ./bjam install > build.log`

I checked the output for errors and it looks clean - nothing reported. I have all the boost libraries and headers under `/usr/local`. I checked my Asio project and it all works fine against this build (no boost log) . I created a new project for the log tutorials, set the library path and the include path and added lboost_log to the linker options.

The problem comes when trying to use the tutorial programs for Boost log - either as detailed in the Boost Log docs [here](http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/log/tutorial/trivial_filtering.html) or in the example included in the files from svn [here](https://boost-log.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/boost-log/trunk/boost-log/libs/log/example/trivial/main.cpp)

The example from SVN looks like this:

```
/*
 *          Copyright Andrey Semashev 2007 - 2011.
 * Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0.
 *    (See accompanying file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at
 *          http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
 */
/*!
 * \file   main.cpp
 * \author Andrey Semashev
 * \date   07.11.2009
 *
 * \brief  An example of trivial logging.
 */

// #define BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK 1
// #define BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK 1

#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/filters.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Trivial logging: all log records are written into a file
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << "A trace severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << "A debug severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "An informational severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(warning) << "A warning severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << "An error severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(fatal) << "A fatal severity message";

    // Filtering may also be applied
    using namespace boost::log;

    core::get()->set_filter
    (
        filters::attr< trivial::severity_level >("Severity") >= trivial::info
    );

    // Now the first two lines will not pass the filter
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << "A trace severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << "A debug severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "An informational severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(warning) << "A warning severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << "An error severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(fatal) << "A fatal severity message";

    return 0;
}
```

When I build the code, I get two errors:

Semantic Issue
  Overloaded 'operator>>' must have at least one parameter of class or enumeration type
Semantic Issue
  Overloaded 'operator<<' must have at least one parameter of class or enumeration type

and the error is reported in the file explicit_operator_bool.hpp from Boost Log at these lines:

```
.
.
.
} // namespace boost

// These operators are not found through ADL
template< typename T > void operator<< (T const&,     boost::log::aux::unspecified_bool_type);
template< typename T > void operator>> (T const&, boost::log::aux::unspecified_bool_type);

#define BOOST_LOG_EXPLICIT_OPERATOR_BOOL()\
.
.
.
```

the stack I get in Xcode is as follows:

```
/usr/local/include/boost/log/utility/explicit_operator_bool.hpp:67:29: error: overloaded 'operator>>' must have at least one parameter of class or enumeration type [2]
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/log/attributes/attribute_name.hpp:27:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/log/attributes/attribute_set.hpp:28:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/log/sources/basic_logger.hpp:37:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/log/sources/severity_logger.hpp:27:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/log/trivial.hpp:25:
In file included from /Volumes/Macintosh HD 2/code/Logging Tut   1/loggingTut1/loggingTut1/main.cpp:18:
Overloaded 'operator>>' must have at least one parameter of class or enumeration type in /usr/local/include/boost/log/utility/explicit_operator_bool.hpp
```

Comment: boost::log isn't yet a supported boost library. So its no surprise that it doesn't compile on every conceivable platform and compiler..

Answer (score 1):

so kinda answering my own question (as it might help other Xcode/OSX users out there).

Looking at the explicit_operator.bool.hpp file, there is some conditional code in there that allows us to bypass the problem templates by setting:

```
#define BOOST_LOG_NO_UNSPECIFIED_BOOL
```

the tutorials then compile and run for me.

What i'm not sure about is why this is needed or what the effect downstream might be (note that like a lot of users, i'm interested in a quick and efficient way to get a lightweight logging framework and if we have to spend time investigating the inner workings of the framework it kinda nullifies the point...)

As the comment says, its not yet a supported library so perhaps its unfair to expect too much at this stage.

Chris